# powershell lint says variable assigned but never used. no i am using

Tags: powershell

## Goal

I want to know, why am I getting this message?

```
The variable 'existModuleName' is assigned but never used.PSScriptAnalyzer(PSUseDeclaredVarsMoreThanAssignments)
```

[image]

If possible, I want to rewrite the code so that the message is not displayed.

And I want to know, Is this bug or syntax error?

## Code

```
function Get-SayHeyYou {
    param(
    )
    [bool]$existModuleName = $false
    (1..3) | ForEach-Object {
        if ($_ -eq 2) {
            $existModuleName = $true
        }
    }
    if ($existModuleName) {
        Write-Host "hey you!"
    }
}

Get-SayHeyYou
```

## My thinking

After first assigning `$false`. When `$_` is `2`, `$true` is assigned by `if`, And used in the last `if`.

What's more, when I run this code, it says "hey you!" As expected. I don't think there is any problem with the scope of variables.

## Tried

I tried to add `Write-Host $existModuleName`.

```
function Get-SayHeyYou {
    param(
    )
    [bool]$existModuleName = $false
    (1..3) | ForEach-Object {
        if ($_ -eq 2) {
            $existModuleName = $true
        }
    }
    if ($existModuleName) {
        Write-Host "hey you!"
        Write-Host $existModuleName
    }
}

Get-SayHeyYou
```

I added `Write-Host $ existModuleName`. There seems to be no particular change.

The output of this code is below.

```
hey you!
True
```

## Environment

- Powershell 7.1.5
- Windows 10 Pro 21H1
- VSCode

  - Version: 1.61.2 (system setup)
  - Commit: 6cba118ac49a1b88332f312a8f67186f7f3c1643
  - Date: 2021-10-19T14:57:20.575Z
  - Electron: 13.5.1
  - Chrome: 91.0.4472.164
  - Node.js: 14.16.0
  - V8: 9.1.269.39-electron.0
  - OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19043

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is [a well-known false positive in PSScriptAnalyzer](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSScriptAnalyzer/issues/1354). You are not doing anything wrong.

You may disable it inline with a special attribute, like so:

```
function Get-SayHeyYou {
    [Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessageAttribute('PSUseDeclaredVarsMoreThanAssignments', 'existModuleName',
        Justification = 'variable is used in another scope')]
    param()
    [bool]$existModuleName = $false
    (1..3) | ForEach-Object {
        if ($_ -eq 2) {
            $existModuleName = $true
        }
    }
    if ($existModuleName) {
        Write-Host "hey you!"
    }
}

Get-SayHeyYou
```

If you prefer not to modify the code, you could also completely disable the rule by having a file containing your PSScriptAnalyzer settings, and then you can point vscode to look at it. [See also this comment](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSScriptAnalyzer/issues/1354#issuecomment-601434387) and some of the others.

[Also here is a sample repository showing use with vscode and custom rule settings](https://github.com/bergmeister/PSScriptAnalyzer-VSCodeIntegration).

The disadvantage of disabling the rule completely is that you will miss legitimate times when you assigned a variable without using it.

But this is currently the tradeoff we must contend with.

頑張ってね！

Comment: ありがとう。I'm trying various things. If I use `foreach ($ item in (1..3))` instead of `(1..3) | Foreach-Object`, the message does not appear. Are there any past cases where you have trouble with the difference in behavior from this? And why difference in behavior from this?

Comment: @ShortArrow the way you are using it very much ok. The issue is with the way PSScriptAnalyzer works. It is explained a little in the GitHub issue I linked, but basically it's because the analyzer can only work within a certain scope. However, the `[ScriptBlock]`s that you pass to certain special cmdlets like `ForEach-Object` do not get used the same as if you write your own function to accept and execute a ScriptBlock. These special cmdlets run in the same scope as the caller. So in short, you are OK, but PSSA cannot determine that, so you must decide when the warning is not useful.

Comment: `foreach` in your example is the `foreach` statement, which is different from `ForEach-Object` (a command). The statement does not start a new scope, so PSSA can analyze it correctly.

Answer (score 3):

I know this post is old at this point, but I wanted to provide a simple solution for other people, like me, who made their way here.

A simple, albeit not the prettiest, is to add the line of code below:
$null = $variable

You of course want to add it inside the same scope where you are getting the warning. $null is a built in variable and can be used to remedy a lot of PowerShell's little quirks.

I use "$null = " all the time to stop certain lines of code from writing output to the console. For example, adding an entry to an array: $array.Add($entry) will output the index that the variable $entry was placed in. Using "$null = $array.Add($entry)" will stop that output.

Comment: It's cool. also, `> $null` or `| $null` too. You have inspired me to come up with a different approach.

Comment: this is ok but it is modifying the code even moreso than adding the attribute to ignore the rule within a certain scope. This also makes the code less clear, so I would personally avoid this and look to other solutions, but +1 for adding another approach.